# Change attribute using php & querypath

Tags: php, querypath

I want to use PHP & QueryPath to find all images in a document, then modify its `src` like this:

I want to change

```
http://test.com/test/name.jpg
```

to

```
http://example.com/xxx/name.jpg
```

I can find the specific class name using

```
$qp2 = $qp->find('body');
```

Now when I want to find all `img` on it to change the `src`:

```
foreach ($qp2->find('img') as $i) {
    //here change the src
}
```

But when I execute

```
echo $qp2->html();
```

I see only last image. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
foreach($qp2->find('img') as $key as $img) {
    echo $img->html();
}
```

Sometimes you have to use top() or end() when you are re-using the qp object.  Something like:

$qp = htmlqp($lpurl);

```
foreach ($qp->find('img') as $key => $img){ 
  print_r($img->attr('src'));
  $url = parse_url ($img->attr('src'));
  print_r($url);
  echo '<br/>';
  if (!isset($url['scheme']) && !isset($url['host']) && !empty($url['path'])){
    $newimg = $htmlpath . '/' . $url['path'];
    $img->end()->attr('src', $newimg);
    echo $img->html();
  }
}

foreach ($qp->top()->find('script') as $key => $script){ 
  print_r($script->attr('src'));
  $url = parse_url ($script->attr('src'));
  print_r($url);
  if (!isset($url['scheme']) && !isset($url['host']) && !empty($url['path'])){
    $newjs = $htmlpath . '/' . $url['path'];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'this is the modified ' . $newjs;
  }
}
```